# Unable to move cursor using mouse in the textarea on custom overlay view google maps

Tags: javascript

I have added a textarea to the custom overlay of google maps. The keyboard events work fine. But im unable to move cursor using mouse in that textarea.

customInfoWindow.prototype.draw = function(latlng) {

```
      var point, panes, me = this, closeImg, div, that = this;
      // Check if the div has been created.
      if(latlng){

        this.latlng_ = latlng;
      }
      div = this.div_;
      if (!div) {

        // Create a overlay text DIV
        div = this.div_ = document.createElement('DIV');
        this.div =div;
        // Create the DIV representing our CustomInfoWindow
        div.style.border = "none";
        div.style.position = "absolute";
        div.style.paddingLeft = "0px";
        div.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        $(div).addClass('custom-info-panel');
        div.style.display = 'none';
        // Then add the overlay to the DOM
        panes = this.getPanes();
        panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(div);
        if(this.callback){
          this.callback(this.div_, this.infoView);
        }
        if(this.showCloseBtn){
          $(div).append('<div class="info-close btn-close" id="btn_close"></div>');
          closeImg = div.querySelector('#btn_close');
          closeImg.style.cursor = "pointer";
          $(this.div_).find('#btn_close').bind( "click", function(event) {\
            $('.popover').removeClass('in').remove();
            me.div_.style.display = 'none';
            if(typeof me.infoView.marker != 'undefined' && me.infoView.marker.update_type == 'alert'){

              var trip_id = me.div_.getElementsByClassName("alert_trip_code")[0].innerHTML.trim();
              $(".alert_info_contact_details_" + trip_id).css("display", "none");
            }
            event.stopPropagation();
            // clear the timeout which is set to toggle window.
            that.stopTimeout();
          });
        }
      }

      // Position the overlay
      point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng_);
      if (point) {

        div.style.left = (point.x + 10)  + 'px';
        div.style.top = (point.y - 15) + 'px';
      }
    };
```

This is my code to to draw the custom overlay. On this overlay im not able to move cursor with mouse. I can move the cursor with my keyboard.

Comment: please show your code and a jsfiddle. no on ecan help without seeing the issue. what does "unable to move cursor using mouse in that textarea" mean?

Comment: a little example would be helpful

Comment: Mouse click event is getting fired, but if i try to click mouse in between the text in the textarea, im not able to do so.